# How can i make history in code. Java language

Tags: java, methods, history

I'm learning java now, sorry if you didn't get it.

Here is the "money transfer" method, it works with constructor in other class.

The code does not end by itself, it constantly returns.

I need to save these parameters (username, transfer amount) and execute this later.

```
public static String moneyTransfer() {
        System.out.println("Enter the name to whom you want to transfer funds");
        String nametransfer = scanner.nextLine();
        String nametransf = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the amount to transfer to the user " + nametransfer);
        int transfermoney = scanner.nextInt();
        Moneytransfer moneytr = new Moneytransfer(nametransf, transfermoney);
        int resulttransfer = balance-transfermoney;
        System.out.println("You transferred  "+transfermoney+" to user: "+nametransf);
        System.out.println("balance: "+resulttransfer);
        return startPanel();
    }
```

```
                            idk(
```

Comment: Aren't they already stored in the memory?  
        ```String nametransfer = scanner.nextLine();
        String nametransf = scanner.nextLine();```

Comment: Be more specific, do you need to record all of the usernames and transfter amounts? You can use HashMap for that if username must be linked to the transfer amount

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html

Answer (score 1):

You can store them with a `List` in package `java.util`.
As you are new to programming, you might not understand what I am talking about. Just keep learning and you will realise.